# How to push mp3 to srs with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I push my MP3 file like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -re -stream_loop -1 -i ./ring.mp3 -c copy -f mp3 rtmp://${domain}/live/test
```

But the PotPlayer couldn't accept it well.

Answer (score 1):

For FFmpeg, the format you should use `flv` instead of `mp3`, like this:

```sh
ffmpeg.exe -re -stream_loop -1 -i ./ring.mp3 -c copy \
  -f flv rtmp://${domain}/live/test

# Or transcode the sample file of SRS
ffmpeg -re -i srs/trunk/doc/source.flv -vn -c:a libmp3lame \
  -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

Then play by ffplay:

```
ffplay rtmp://localhost/live/test
```

Recommend to use AAC instead MP3, because AAC is more widely used, so you could transcode to aac by:

```sh
ffmpeg -f flv -i rtmp://localhost/live/livestream -c:v copy -c:a aac \
  -f flv -y rtmp://localhost/live/test2
```

> Note that WebRTC use opus as audio codec.